# Django managing the icons and images

Tags: python, html, django, web

This is a Best practice question about how to manage my media in my django site.

I know this is not an "confusion with a code snippet" question like the most of the questions, but seriously i could imagine that this is a dilemma of some of the web developers.

Instead of managing all of my media content by a model with a key of **ImageField** key like this:

```py
class myLogos(models.Model):
   foo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/')
```

I was thinking its more "manageable"  to store all of my media content in a kind of separated server, and to call a specific image everytime from my template, like this:

```py
<img src="https://www.mysitepictures.com/app1/foo1.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<img src="https://www.mysitepictures.com/app2/foo2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

The reason is, i found it way too complicated to display images in an django project with multiple applications on it.

Is that a great idea to have kind of an third party server just for calling the images from it?

If not, then how should i manage a huge django project with a hundreds of images on the whole site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many big sites do like this. This is effective when you have a file count restriction or size limits on your server/hosting. But if you have only 100-1000 images, don't do this. You can never be sure that your images can be there forever.

Comment: Yes, But im afraid in the future there will be more than 1000 images on the site and it will be hard to be managed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jim, i'm using now Amazon S3, but Cloudinary could be a good option as well.

https://cloudinary.com/

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/s3/

Both have libs in python to manage files to their servers ;)

Comment: Im going to look forward to both of them. Thank you

Comment: For cloudinary i found this tutorial for the integration:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_integration

For Amazon S3 thre is this lib: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html